# weblogic 12c + websphere mq 6

Tags: weblogic, ibm-mq

I'm can't find instruction for integration websphere mq 6  + weblogic 12 c by websphere native protocol (no jms!). It possible? Goal - deploy mdb in weblogic for getting message from websphere mq queue.
and response. 
Please help with link or instruction.
Alex

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want to do or what you have tried. Does this help? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0604_kesavan/0604_kesavan.html

Comment: Now i'm finding information about it. But all instruction only with jms. No jms protocol because we must using a specific mq api values (MQC.MQMF_SEGMENTATION_ALLOWED e.t.c.) for legacy applications.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the option of using WebLogic's Foreign JMS provider configuration is not available to you as you want to NOT use the JMS API, but MQ's specific API, correct?

If that is the case you could always try to write some MQ Client code using the MQ API, as you would for a stand-alone application, and then deploy it inside WebLogic, although I'm not sure whether that would give you any real benefit.

One thing I am pretty sure you will NOT be able to do is write a Message-Driven Bean which connects to an MQ Series queue using the MQ API. MDBs are a Java EE concept and they are meant to connect to JMS providers.

Comment: Thank you for response. Ok, i'm understand.